# files in build folder randomly disappear and reappear when I use ionic build --prod

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

On my production server, I run "ionic build --prod" and it generates a www folder with www/build

Initially, everything works fine when I point apache to the www folder.

Randomly I will try to load the site and it will be a blank screen. If I refresh and wait a few minutes, it comes back. Upon inspecting it shows that main.css, main.js, vendor.css, vendor.js are 404. Upon ssh'ing into the server, sure enough, those files are no longer in the build folder.

If I wait a few minutes, they seem to magically reappear there.

Is "ionic build --prod" not the correct command to generate the www folder to use an ionic app as a PWA?

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution. I created a deploy script which copies the contents of www to another folder, and then pointed apache at that folder. I still do not know why the contents of the build folder were mysteriously vanishing, but at least I have a solid workaround.